# Editable Grids control and the Status Reason field

Tags: grid, status

The Editable Grid was a nice addition bringing the CRM Dynamics to a higher standard.
My question is related the Status Reason field.

We know that the **Status** field cannot be updated from an editable grid and i think I understand the technical reasons behind.

However, I have expected that the **Status Reason** can be. Currently on my systems (on-premise CRM 365 V9) the field is locked and shows the lock icon next to it when placed in a View.

I've started to suspect this field follows the same internal model as the **Status** but I would like to confirm with other experts which might have noticed the same behavior.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see also on this [blog post](https://themscrmexpert.wordpress.com/2016/11/14/d365-new-features-editable-grid-part-1/) the Status Reason and Status are read only fields on an editable grid.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing me to this. this is what I suspected too.